# Safely invert floating point calculation

Tags: c++, floating-point, rounding-error

I wonder what is the correct way to invert this calculation:

```
float x = a * 25.0f + b; // where a and b are integers and b is in [0-25[
```

How can I avoid possible floating-point rounding errors. The answers are obvious even if x has some error so it should be possible to implement.

Comment: could you define a ***floating-point error***

Comment: What does it mean to *"invert this calculation"*? That's not a well-defined concept.

Comment: Could you define "invert"?

Comment: Are there any range limits on `a`?

Comment: To get back the input, so the value of ```a``` and ```b```

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan a should be between 200.000 and 1.000.000

Comment: `a = ((int) (x + 0.5)) / 25;` and `b = ((int) (x + 0.5)) % 25;`?

Comment: and presumably x only has integral values, otherwise it is completely impossible for integer values a and b to produce a non-integer x...

Comment: @BaummitAugen you get (1, 0) since b should be less than 25.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko That is a correct formula, thank you :)

Comment: If you have `x` but neither `a` nor `b`, you can not possibly get the values of both `a` and `b`. To get `b` you need to know `a`, and the opposite.

Comment: Can we assume `float` is IEEE 754 32-bit binary floating point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using *modulo arithmetics*, i.e. integer division `/` and remainder `%`:

```
int a = ((int) (x + 0.5f)) / 25; 
int b = ((int) (x + 0.5f)) % 25;
```

if `x` can have *round up errors*, e.g. `x = 53.999997` instead of `54` then *round* it to the nearest integer: `(int) (x + 0.5f)`. Please, notice that `x` should be *small enough* to be cast to `int`: `x = 1e30f` will definitely fail.

Answer (score 1):

For the range of a you gave, you can't safely get b back.

For a=10^6, you need 20bits. If you multiply by 25, you need 5 more bits. Thus, for extreme values of a, you'll need 25 bits of significand to represent x. IEEE 754 single precision float only offer you 24. That means that x may loose the least significant bit. Instead of the true value x, you have x+/-1.

But you have access to some more information:

- if x<2^24, then you know that you can retrieve b and a by naive algorithm
- if x >= 2^24 and the significand is odd `((int)(x))%4 == 2`, then you know that no rounding did take place. Indeed, cancelling the last bit is a case of exact tie, and lead to a rounding to nearest even in IEEE 754 default rounding mode.
- only in the case of x >= 2^24 and the significand is even, you cannot conclude, and you have 3 possible values for the couple {a,b}.

Conclusion: you shall use double precision here